# Pointer arithmetic with 2D vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand pointer arithmetic in 2D vector.

I thought that if I have 2D vector at the size: `M[3][3]` and `*ptr=&M[0][0]`
than `ptr[4]` is equal to `M[1][2]`, but it seems to be wrong.

Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: From what book/reference/web page did you get the idea that ptr[4] is M[1][2]? So we can suggest a better resource

Comment: Is this a standard library vector?  As in `std::vector<std::vector<int>> M(3, std::vector<int>(3))` ?  Or is this just an array?  `int M[3][3]`

Answer (score 2):

2D arrays are arranged in [Row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Row-major_order), so the 3 columns of row 0 come first, followed by the 3 columns of row 1, etc. Your concept is correct, but your counting is off: it's M[1][1].

http://www.ideone.com/ivoWq

Note that you might run into problems due to [pointer aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing) depending on your code and how agressively your compiler tries to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

M[3][3] is laid out in memory as [0,0] [0,1] [0,2] [1,0] [1,1] [1,2] [2,0] [2,1] [2,2]

so ptr+4 would be the fourth element of the array [1,1] but since you defined it as a 2d array you can't use a 1d index as shorthand.

Comment: What do you mean? Why can't you?

Comment: Because Mr Ritche decided you couldn't - it's part of the C spec.

Comment: When you declare a 2D vector in c++, it creates a 1D vector of pointers, and each of those points to a separate address, so the addresses are just not laid out in order the way you would use them as if it was 1D

Comment: @DanF: I just noticed he said vector, not array.  But a 2d vector is not a vector of pointers, it is a vector of vectors.

Comment: Hmm true, making the memory layout even more different.  I assumed he was referring to arrays given his pointer syntax in the question

Comment: @DanF: If that was your assumption(it was mine also), then your statement was wrong.  A 2d array is an array of arrays, not an array of pointers.  All the elements are contiguous in memory.

Comment: If it is declared on the stack it is, certainly not if it is a dynamic 2D array